# Is that possible disable device switch in Visual Studio Code when develop flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is that possible disable device switch in Visual Studio Code when develop flutter ?

What's my condition:

1. I have simulator opened, and debug for a while, code for a while.
2. Then I need to plugin my phone to charge power of phone. But vscode too clever to switch the device to my phone automatic.
3. And then when I debug, I always found why it's build slow now?  And found out that it's debugging on my phone now...

Any idea to solve this ?

PS: I didn't always have usb power for my phone beside my computer.

Comment: Is that easy steps to change ? since I need to debug device at sometime too.

Comment: it would be good if there's a config in vscode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that it's possible to disable that (default is on). Go to User Settings -> Extensions -> Dart & Flutter

[image: VS Code Extension option]

You can also select device with this action:
[image: Flutter: Select Device action]